# Как в Unity запустить обход в глубину параллельно?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Я бы хотел сделать настольную крестико-нолико-подобную игру, в которой человек может играть с человеком (на одном устройстве), и человек может играть с ботом, который выбирает ходы обходом дерева позиций в глубину (например, альфа-бета отсечение).

Далее в коде `GameState, Move, PlayerColor` не наследуют `MonoBehavior` и вообще изолированы от логики Unity.

Класс `Player` имеет наследников `Human, Bot`. Метод `Player.GetTopMoves(GameState gameState)` возвращает список некоторых выбранных ходов. Стратегия выбора ходов у каждого наследника своя:

`Human` - это, по сути, пользователь, и выбор хода эквивалентен тому, что пользователь сам выбирает ход нажатием мыши по некоторым объектам.

`Bot` - выбирает ходы обходом в глубину дерева возможных позиций

В следующем коде, очевидно, метод `StartGame` абсолютно непригоден для использования в Unity, так как

1. сам метод работает пока не закончится вся настольная игра (скорее всего его нужно будет переписать как корутину?)
2. метод выбора хода тоже занимает большое время (человек долго думает над ходом и бот долго считает)

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private BoardViewer _boardViewer;

    private GameState _gameState;
    private Dictionary<PlayerColor, Player> _players;
    private Player _playerToMove;


    public void StartGame(Player whitePlayer, Player blackPlayer)
    {
        Dictionary<PlayerColor, Player> players = new Dictionary<PlayerColor, Player>
        {
            { PlayerColor.White, whitePlayer },
            { PlayerColor.Black, blackPlayer },
        };
        _gameState = GameState.NewGame;
        

        while (_gameState.IsOver() == false)
        {
            _playerToMove = _players[_gameState.PlayerColorToMove];
            
            // логика выбора хода зависит от типа Игрока
            Move bestMove = _playerToMove.GetTopMoves(_gameState)[0];

            _boardViewer.SpawnStone(...);
            _gameState = _gameState.ApplyMove(bestMove);
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, я бы хотел адоптировать код выше для использования в проекте Unity, но абсолютно не имею понятия как это можно сделать. Не хотел бы запускать выбор хода корутиной (так как где-то вычитал, что тяжелые вычисления для этого менее пригодны), но тогда и Thread не подходит, так как `Player` (точнее его наследник `Human`) наследует `MonoBehavior` (насколько я знаю, это потоко небезопасно).

Возможно стоит забить на общий класс Player и вместо `Game` сделать две версии `PvP` и `PvE`?
Спасибо

Comment: Не в тему, но `_gameState.IsOver() == false` - это вы bool сравниваете с bool, чтобы получить bool. Надо это переписать так `!_gameState.IsOver()`.

Comment: @aepot, я всё время не замечаю этот знак. Поэтому пишу более явно

Comment: Выглядит как ошибка новичка. Учитесь замечать.

Comment: @aepot, я тоже так пишу. Знак мало заметный, без него код читается в сто раз проще, а некоторые ещё и `== true` тоже пишут, для симметрии.

Comment: @Yaroslav в студии шрифт покрупнее можоо сделать :) Мне проще читать 1 символ вместо 6. А если много условий, то вообще выглядит как ад с этими bool == false и string.ToString().

Comment: @aepot, 1 символ прочесть быстрее и легче чем 6, ну спасибо что пробелы не посчитал. Кому ты лапу на уши вешаешь? `== false` мы не читаем, а просто видим. Длинные `if`, это такой не читаемый зоопарк операторов, которые считаются косяком? Ты про него?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть же методы `Update` и `FixedUpdate`, здесь по сути ничего изобретать не надо. Это вполне себе заменяет цикл `while`. Если нужна теория для разобраться - почитайте про шаблон проектирования "конечный автомат" или еще его называют "машина состояний".

К примеру, возмем цикл, умножающий число на 2 десять раз, для наглядности буду использовать тот же `while`

```cs
int i = 0;
int number = 1;
while (i < 10)
{
    number *= 2;
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Выведем саму операцию в отдельный метод.

```cs
public void Multiply(int number, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < count)
    {
        number *= 2;
        i++;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Тогда это вызвать можно будет так

```cs
int number = Multiply(1, 10);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Вот по сути получился метод, содержащий всю логику внутри.

Этот цикл не завершится, пока не закончит считать. Когда надо еще что-то делать или делать несколько дел одновременно, вызывая итерации цикла по одной, используют конечный автомат.

Вынесем логику в отдельный класс. Переименую i в state

```cs
class CounterMachine
{
    private int _state;
    private int _number;
    private readonly int _count;

    public bool Finished { get; private set; }

    public CounterMachine(int number, int count)
    {
        _number = number;
        _count = count;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (_state < _count)
        {
            _number *= 2;
            _state++;
        }
        else if (_state == _count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_number);
            _state++;
            Finished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот вся логика упакована в некий черный ящик.

Вызов этого монстра будет выглядеть так, что надо его создать и вызывать обновление, пока он не закончит работать.

```cs
var counterMachine = new CounterMachine(1, 10);
while (!counterMachine.Finished)
    counterMachine.Update();
```

А теперь представьте, что вот это создание класса и вызовы `Update` будет делать Unity за вас, останется только написать саму машину. А сама машина - это и есть скрипт Unity. Единственное отличие в том, что эта машина бесконечная, будет выполняться, пока существует объект, к которому прицеплен скрипт.

```cs
public class Counter : MonoBehavior
{
    private int _state;
    private int _number = 1;
    private int _count = 10;
    private bool _finished;

    void Update()
    {
        if (_finished)
            return;

        if (_state < _count)
        {
            _number *= 2;
            _state++;
        }
        else if (_state == _count)
        {
            _finished = true;
            OnFinished();
        }
    }

    private void OnFinished()
    {
        // вывести _number
    }
}
```

Эта логика как бы ложится на игру. Внутри метода вы делаете одну итерацию обсчета, меняете состояние игры и поехали дальше по кругу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но есть с моей стороны следующее недопонимание:
Bot использует метод GetTopMoves и это у него в среднем занимает секунд 10 (так как обход в глубину - длительная операция). Если я вызову его в Update, вся игра встанет на 10 секунд.

Comment: @SdxSdySdz Ну внутри метода `GetTopMoves` цикл же, верно? Значит из него можно сделать машину состояний. А пока идет обсчет в машине можно на экране показывать, что "робот думает". Об этом и пишу в ответе. И сдается мне, его можно оптимизировать так, чтобы это не длилось 10 секунд. Потому что максимальная нагрузка на проц, даже если это сделать в другом потоке - штука, если и не вешающая, то тормозящая игру.